# Is there any simple way to return single value from the list in python?

Tags: python, numbers

Let's say we have a list: x = [5, 5, 2, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4]. How can I return the number which happens only once in this list, i.e. 2?

This question was asked while trying to solve the ["Find the odd int"](https://www.codewars.com/kata/54da5a58ea159efa38000836) problem on Codewars. Initially I did not understand correctly the task, but could have solved it much easier, so read it carefully before solving :)

Finally following code was used to solve it (it's **not entire solution**, but the part of it, which is used after creating the dictionary out of the input):

```
return [int(k) for k,v in d.items() if v%2==1][0]
```

Comment: @the.salman.a: Not really - that's for when you already know which item you want to count. As the top answer states, performance becomes terrible if you count all the items in the list.

Comment: what have you  tried so far to solve your problem.Stack overflow is not a free coding service. You have to show your effort too.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: counting all the items in a list can trivially be done in O(N) time, using the right approach.

Comment: It was just a part of another task. I tried, but could not find the same  question.

Comment: @VikasDamodar, I did not know about the Counter collection and tried to solve this with standard for loop and if... else procedure

Comment: @user2467011 that you can add to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> x = [5, 5, 2, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 8]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(x)
>>> [item[0] for item in c.items() if item[1]==1]
[2, 8]
```

Comment: It's not safe to assume they know there will be only one item that has one occurrence.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, better make the solution more general.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [**`collections.Counter`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to achieve this. Below *list comprehension* will return list of all elements which occurred once in your list:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x = [5, 5, 2, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4]

>>> [k for k, v in Counter(x).items() if v==1]
[2]
```